# .htaccess vanity URLs - rewrite multiple GETs within subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, vanity-url

I've been trying to rewrite URLs within a subfolder, but without success. Nothing simply happens - no URL is rewritten at all.
Please help!

I want this:
www.example.com/fruits/?fruitName=apples&mode=buy

...to become this:
www.example.com/fruits/apples/buy/

These rewrites will only occur in the /fruits/ folder.
How is this done?

Here's the code that I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/fruits/$ /fruits/?fruitName=$1&mode=$2
```

Thank you!

Comment: post your code. hard to point you in the right direction with no code and no description of the problem beyond not having success.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the code I had, but I'll see if I can find it again. Give me a few minutes please.

Comment: Posted the code. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `/fruits/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fruits/

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ ?fruitName=$1&mode=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Bumped into a small problem though - I'd like the .htaccess rewrite to allow hyphens. What should I change? Should I ask a new StackOverflow question about this?

Comment: That's a minor change so no need of a new question. See edited rule.